# Using JS 1.7+ keywords in a blob Worker

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

My problem is that when I'm trying to use JavaScript 1.7+ keywords, say `let`, in a Web Worker, which source is a blob, it silently fails.
The code I use is

```
function myWorker() {
  let msg = 'hello';
  postMessage(msg);
}

let blob = new Blob(
  ['(' + myWorker + ')();'],
  {'type': 'text/javascript;version=1.8'}
);
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let worker = new Worker(url);
worker.onmessage = function(msg) alert('got message: ' + msg.data);
worker.postMessage(null);
```

The same code works fine if you replace first `let` keyword with `var`.
Is there any way to make Firefox (I checked it with versions 21.0 and last stable 23.0) understand new JS1.7+ in a blob?

Comment: Does this problem persist if you set _type_ to 1. `text/javascript`, 2. `application/javascript`, 3. `text/ecmascript`, 4. `application/ecmascript`. EDIT: There seems to be an open bug about this on bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=487070

Comment: Forgot to mention; the `let` etc. in _FireFox/Gecko_ is actually from _JavaScript 1.7_ or the _ECMAScript 4_ specification, the _ECMAScript 6/Harmony_ version just carries over the bit of _ES4_. Either way _JavaScript 1.8.x_ is not the right thing to call it. Reading the bug report, everything new after _JavaScript 1.5_ is not guaranteed to work in _WebWorkers_ as they are currently.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug. I've changed `1.8` to `1.7+` in the question.